# What is a "type" as mentioned in the Java tutorial?

Tags: java

**Source:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

> You may also occasionally see the term "member" used as well. A type's fields, methods, and nested types are collectively called its members."

While defining *member* the tutorial uses the term *type*, in this context it doesn't look like they mean data type. I can't find a correct definition on Google. Maybe its something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the `javax.lang.model` package and especially [`javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html) which may provide some further insight for you.

Answer (score 8):

In this context "type" means "class".

In other contexts it may mean "a class or a primitive type", but since they talk about types having members, they mean specifically classes. Same goes for nested types: only classes can be nested inside other classes; all primitive types are built into the language, and cannot be nested.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like they mean the class of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Java has 3 types.

- ReferenceType - classes, interfaces and arrays
- PrimitiveType - primitives
- NullType - null

These are defined in the [Java Language Specification section 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1). Any time you see an API doc or tutorial referring to a `type`, this is what they are talking about.

In this particular case the tutorial is using type to refer to a ReferenceType. The definition of a class and interface (a type) will usually also define members of that type.